# Reducing number of ORM queries in Django web application

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm

I'm trying to improve the performance of one of my Django applications to make them run just a bit smoother, as part of a first iteration in improving what I currently have running. When doing some profiling I've noticed that I have a very high number of SQL queries being executed on a couple of pages.

The dashboard page for instance easily has 250+ SQL queries being executed. Further investigation pointed me to the following piece of code in my `views.py`:

```
for project in projects:
            for historicaldata in project.historical_data_for_n_months_ago(i):
                for key in ('hours', 'expenses'):
                    history_data[key] = history_data[key] + getattr(historicaldata, key)
```

Relevant function in `models.py` file:

```
def historical_data_for_n_months_ago(self, n=1):
    n_year, n_month = n_months_ago(n)

    try:
        return self.historicaldata_set.filter(year=n_year, month=n_month)
    except HistoricalData.DoesNotExist:
        return []
```

As you can see, this will cause a lot of queries being executed for each project in the list. Originally this was set-up this way to keep functionality centrally at the model level and introduce convenience functions across the application.

What would be possible ways on how to reduce the number of queries being executed when loading this page? I was thinking on either removing the convince function and just working with `select_related()` in the view, but, it would still need a lot of queries in order to filter out records for a given year and month.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit** As requested, some more info on the related models.

*Project*

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    total_hours = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total_expenses = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{i.name}".format(i=self)

    def historical_data_for_n_months_ago(self, n=1):
        n_year, n_month = n_months_ago(n)

        try:
            return self.historicaldata_set.filter(year=n_year, month=n_month)
        except HistoricalData.DoesNotExist:
            return []
```

*HistoricalData*

```
class HistoricalData(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.IntegerField()
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    expenses = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Historical data {i.month}/{i.year} for {i.person} ({i.project})".format(i=self)
```

Comment: Could you add related models here?

Comment: Information has been added!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think looping through querysets is ever a good idea. So it would be better if you could find some other way. If you could elaborate your view function and exactly what its supposed be to done maybe I could help further.

If you want all the historical_data entries for a project (reverse related) you need to use prefetch_related. Since you want a specific portion of the historical data associated with said project you need to use it with Prefetch.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
Project.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'historicaldata_set', 
        queryset=HistoricalData.objects.filter(year=n_year, month=n_month)
    )
)
```

After that, you should be looping through this dataset in your django template (if you are using that). You can also pass it to a drf-serializer and that would also get your work done :)

Comment: That looks indeed a good way forward. I'll try that. Basically what is happening in the view is just gathering that data for each year/month combination in scope (usually last 12 months) and then creates a graph out of that data. So not a lot more then pulling it out of the database, maybe doing some rework to get it in the right shape and then pushing it out to the template.

Comment: gotcha, if this was indeed the solution you were looking for please select the answer